# DevOps pipeline, how to tag docker image with timestamp

Tags: docker, tags, devops, pipeline

How can I push docker image and tag with timestamp? I try using $(date:yyyyMMdd), but it not use it as variables.

```
I got:
docker tag myImg:$(date:yyyyMmdd)
instead of:
docker tag myImg:20230101
```

Do I used wrong syntax?

[image]

Comment: Should not be `$(date '+%Y%M%d')`?

Comment: Thanks, but still DevOps try to use it as string, not as variables.